# NoClassDefFoundError when adding new font in iText on AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, itext

I have an appengine java project that includes pdf creation at some point. The pdf document has special font that I'm trying to include with:
`BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont("resources/AlexBrush-Regular.ttf", "", BaseFont.EMBEDDED);`

Code runs perfect locally but when deployed I get the NoClassDefFoundError (stack trace below). Did any one succeeded in adding custom font to iText on appengine? I'm using iTextg-5.4.4

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.nio.MappedByteBuffer is a restricted class. Please see the Google App Engine developer's guide for more details.
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.stub.java.nio.channels.FileChannel_.map(FileChannel.java)
at com.itextpdf.text.io.MappedChannelRandomAccessSource.open(MappedChannelRandomAccessSource.java:104)
at com.itextpdf.text.io.FileChannelRandomAccessSource.<init>(FileChannelRandomAccessSource.java:71)
at com.itextpdf.text.io.RandomAccessSourceFactory.createBestSource(RandomAccessSourceFactory.java:212)
at com.itextpdf.text.io.RandomAccessSourceFactory.createBestSource(RandomAccessSourceFactory.java:193)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray.<init>(RandomAccessFileOrArray.java:147)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.TrueTypeFont.process(TrueTypeFont.java:625)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.TrueTypeFont.<init>(TrueTypeFont.java:369)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.java:705)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.java:621)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.java:456)
at ccfb.server.servlets.PaypalCheckoutServlet.doPost(PaypalCheckoutServlet.java:156)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:266)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:446)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:435)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:442)
at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:186)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:306)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:298)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:439)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Comment: Please don't close this question (I see already one vote to close it), it's genuine and I'll answer it in a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know, you should avoid all file system related operations on GAE. As you can read on the [iTextG page](http://itextpdf.com/product/itextg), some methods in iTextG are to be used only on Android, not on GAE. I quote:

> We have not removed them since they are useful on an Android device,
>   but it doesn't make sense to use them in the context of Google App
>   Engine.

This means that you need to use a `byte[]` if you want to create a `BaseFont` instance. You can't use the `createFont()` method that takes a path to a font program. Instead you need to use the `createFont()` method [that accepts the bytes of the font program](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/BaseFont.html#createFont%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20byte%5B%5D,%20byte%5B%5D,%20boolean%29).

Comment: Thanks Bruno...i should've looked deeper in the createFont() method

Comment: No problem. We should provide better documentation. We're working on it.